# Error when trying compile kernel for OP5T

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile nethunter kernel for OP5T but when I try the command make I have the following error:

```
root@kali:/# make oneplus5-stock_defconfig
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /home/arter97/arm64-gcc/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: /home/arter97/arm64-gcc/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
HOSTCC scripts/basic/fixdep
HOSTCC scripts/basic/bin2c
HOSTCC scripts/kconfig/conf.o
HOSTCC scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
HOSTLD scripts/kconfig/conf
#configuration written to .config
```

The path `/home/arter97/arm64-gcc/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc` doesn't exist on my computer. Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: uff... kali is compiling platform? Please read Kali Linux' own guide what Kali Linux is **not** for: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 1):

> The /home/arter97/arm64-gcc/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc path doesn't exist on my computer. Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Basically, you're trying to use an operating system that was specifically designed to *not* be useful for development tasks for compilation.

You'll have to awkwardly install the necessary toolchains and make everything fit together.

Kali Linux is not meant for this, it's making your life harder, and the Kali Linux community **especially** tells you you shouldn't be using Kali for this: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

So, in all honesty, maybe just use a different Linux, like, say Debian or Ubuntu or Fedora, for which it is trivial to get cross-compiler toolchains set up.

Seriously, getting that compiler chain ready after installing a "normal" debian is

```
apt install gcc-11-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

and that's it. I'm not trying to dissuade you from using Kali because of some personal reason, it's just making your life harder if you're doing anything but covert security research. It's a very specialized tool.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply i will try with manjaro and follow your instructions